# colons in directive names - ng:repeat instead of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Obviously the code here works

```
    <tr ng:repeat="item in invoice.items">
        <td><input type="text" ng:model="item.description"class="input-small"></td>           
        <td><input type="number" ng:model="item.qty" ng:required class="input-mini"></td>
        <td><input type="number" ng:model="item.cost" ng:required class="input-mini"></td>
        <td>{{item.qty * item.cost | currency}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href ng:click="removeItem($index)">&times</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/slav123/75m7e/3/

but why does he use colons?

The docs
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat
say nothing about this syntax.

Comment: Checkout [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) under "Normalization".

Comment: OK, I see now exactly where is allowed. Thanks sir.

Comment: I think answer is they switched conventions in earlier days of angular using `:` to using `-` and needed to stay backward compatible

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> **Best Practice**: Prefer using the dash-delimited format (e.g. ng-bind for ngBind). If you want to use an HTML validating tool, you can instead use the data-prefixed version (e.g. data-ng-bind for ngBind). **The other forms** shown above **are accepted for legacy reasons** but we advise you to **avoid them**.

-- [AngularJS Developer Guide -- Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).